# Android Webview Functions

Tags: android, webview

In iPhone we have functions like webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad to check the Start of loading and finish of particular url.

Do we have anythng like this on Android ?

Comment: Yes.Thnks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    // Do something here
  }

  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    // Do something here
  }

  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    // Do something here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use WebViewClient :

```
private class CustomWebClient extends WebViewClient{

    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {

    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
    {

    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {

    }
}
```

Usage:

webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient());

Every method name is self explanatory and you can also check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html